# 2 fields with numbers...need to add them together for sorting entries by that number

Tags: forms, dynamic, math

I have a channel with 2 fields, "New Square Footage" and "Remodeled Square Footage". I'm displaying both of these numbers in my template. I want to be able to sort the entries by the total of both of those fields. I currently have a form that will sort based on one of those fields and it works fine using Dynamic Parameters http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/dynamic_parameters.html. Any way to add these fields together? I'm not sure if it can be done through the template, or if there needs to be a hidden field in the Publish form that adds them together...Any ideas?

My current form

```
        <ul>
        <li>
        <label>Order By:</label>
        <select name="orderby">
            <option value="project_state">State</option>
            <option value="project_completion_date">Completion Date</option> 
            <option value="project_contract_amount">Contract Amount($)</option>
            <option value="project_new_sq_ft">Square Footage</option>
        </select>
        </li>
        <li>
        <label>Sort:</label>
        <select name="sort">
            <option value="asc">Ascending</option>
            <option value="desc">Descending</option>
        </select>
        </li>
        <li>
        <input type="submit" value="Go!" />
        </li>
    </ul>
```

"prject_new_sq_ft" is one of the fields, I need that to be the total of both fields.

Answer (score 1):

[Math add-on?](http://devot-ee.com/search/results?keywords=math&addon_version_support=ee2)

[This one is free](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-calculator) and has a lot of praise.

But I'm assuming you need the total on the page that receives the form, and as you may not be able to use the add-on as a parameter, it may not work.  Worth a try.

Otherwise what about simply using JQuery/JavaScript on the form onChange event for either/both the fields, that automatically populates a hidden field with the combination of the 2 fields.

**UPDATE:** Another route...

Parent template uses an [add-on](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/server-variable) (there are others) to get the POST or GET variables, you then pass those to the child embed template to be used in the channel:entries, which no longer uses dynamic parameters.

Parent Template:

```
{embed=template-group/child-template 
    orderby="{exp:server_var:server:post var="orderby"}"
    sort="{exp:server_var:server:post var="sort"}"
    combined="{exp:will_hunting:solve_pair}{$result={exp:server_var:server:post var="prject_new_sq_ft"}+{exp:server_var:server:post var="prject_remodel_sq_ft"}}{/exp:will_hunting:solve_pair}"}
```

Child Template:

```
{exp:channel:entries sort="{embed:sort}" orderby="{embed:orderby}" limit="{embed:combined}"}
```

Reading back through your question, I'm a little confused as to what "I want to be able to sort the entries by the total of both of those fields." actually means as you can't "sort" by a number, so in the example above I've just used it for limit to give you the idea and you can manipulate as you see fit.

I've used a different Math add-on, as looking into it MX Calculator won't allow the tags in the parameter, but [this one](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/will-hunting) looks as though it could work (obviously there are [others](http://devot-ee.com/search/results?keywords=math&addon_version_support=ee2)).

It's doubtful that the code above will work without further tweaking, possibly adding parse="inward" to the server_var tags. But hopefully it'll give you the right direction.

Comment: I think since I'm sorting using dynamic parameters, and only passing the name of the field to sort by, adding the numbers in the form template wouldn't do anything. I think I need some kind of fieldtype in the CP that would add the numbers from the other 2 fields and record that sum...might be a custom job?